# Is anti virus a battery hog?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, anti-virus

My university makes you download an anti-virus and something called safeconnect in order to connect to the internet (eduroam). I'm very careful and wouldn't have either on my computer if it was up to me, but unfortunately I have to adhere to their policies.

I downloaded sophos anti-virus for my 2016 tMBP and think it might be draining my battery. When I go to my activity monitor it says SophosServiceManager is using >99% of my CPU, but on the other hand it says SophosUIManager's energy impact is 0. Here's the entires I see:

CPU: 
[image: cpu]
Energy:
[image: energy]
Memory: 
[image: memory]

Does anybody know if an anti-virus is usually a power hog? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Are you saying the university made you download "an anti-virus" and so you downloaded Sophos?  Or did you download something that the university said to download and you also downloaded Sophos?  Did the university mention Sophos by name?  Or any other product?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, AV is a battery hog.

You are looking at three different processes, actually. The first is SophosServiceManager, which looks like the process that is actually doing the scan.  It looks like it's taking tons of CPU (and thus battery).

SophosUIServer probably just displays the little icon in the menu bar, and takes almost no memory.

SophosScanD is yet a third process.

Comment: WHAT DO? WHAT DO?

Comment: I couldn't find anything talking about the processes, so I've got no idea.

Comment: I've uninstall sophos, its a piece of crap.

Comment: @MarksCode If you're looking for a recommendation, I really like Avast, and it's had very little impact on battery life or CPU % (consistently not in the top 10 apps for either of those) and has done a good job with real-time protection and scans. https://www.avast.com/en-us/mac

Comment: Actually, Avast is a well-know system hog, whether it uses battery or not is not something I've investigated, but you can certainly feel it slowing down even a 12-core Mac Pro. *Note:* Since I last used Avast, the latest [AV-TEST](https://www.av-test.org/en/news/news-single-view/strong-protection-for-macos-sierra-12-packages-put-to-the-test/) mentions they may have fixed this in all but download speed.